# making and presenting app tutorial views in Xcode

Tags: ios, user-interface

I have an app that is not super intuitive. I want to take screenshots of the confusing screens and then use MSpaint to write instructions and doodles. When the user opens the view in the app for the first time, I want to present the series of altered screenshots along with an "OK" button. pressing OK will dismiss the screenshot and it will not be shown again. Is there an efficient way to do this? I am new to Swift and Xcode. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) to save the state of the app (tutorial shown or not) - NSUserDefaults saves data between the runs of the app to the device storage.

Then you need to change AppDelegate to change the initial view controller according to the value you saved - that way if tutorial has been shown it will not show again.

Assuming you have var called `toturialShown`
Set it to false and each run check its value to determine if the tutorial needs to be shown
When the user taps on dismiss tutorial button use NSUSerDefaults to save this new status

Store

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(toturialShown, forKey: "toturialShownKey")
```

Retrieve

```
 UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "toturialShownKey")
```

Remove - in case you want to delete it completely from storage

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "toturialShownKey")
```

On AppDelegate in `applicationDidFinishWithOptions` function
(Note that I didn't test the code)

```
var vc = ""
    If toturialShown {
           vc = "regularVC"
    } else {
     vc = "toturialVC"
}
let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vc)
    let initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginSignupVC")

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Note1: you need to add identifiers to you VCs in storyboard

Note 2: if you set your initial VC (on storyboard) to the regular VC, you can change the code above to set the initial VC programmatically only if the tutorial has not been shown, results in slightly more elegant code

Comment: This code is going to launch the tutorial right off the bat when the app is opened for the first time? I wanted to only launch the tutorial when certain view controllers are presented.

Comment: This will switch between 2 VC - if tutorial was shown the regular VC will be shown if this the first time the app runs it will show the tutorial VC

Comment: When I dismiss the tutorial, do I have to segue to the normal VC?

Comment: I am getting "use of unresolved identifier 'storyboard'

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tested the code. Replace it with mainStoryboard (answer edited)

Comment: i also needed to add :    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) It works now. Thank you for your patience.