# How to skip login screen from app delegate in tabbed bar App

Tags: ios, swift, redirect

I am trying to skip the login screen when I am close the app and relaunch again.

I got many answered questions but none of them with tabbed bar application.
So the challenge is I have many root view controllers which are distract my entire project if tried to assign a root directly with SecondViewController.

Here an image of my project:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xilpI.jpg

1. is the tabbed bar app
2. navigation to index 0 tab bar
3. login screen
4. profile page

I want to skip login screen and show profile page direct since my:

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "USER_KEY_UID") != nil {
    /*provide me the correct code can be applied here with out distracting the tabbed bar in the bottom  */
}
```

Note: the code above I applied in appDelegete

Comment: I think this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45772772/4261455

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for the tab bar controller. It should be sub class of UITabBarController

consider this as main view controller and add the login controller like below in your app delegate.

```
if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "USER_KEY_UID") != nil {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: [Main Stroyboard] , bundle: nil)
        let mainVcIntial = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: [Main VC])
        let mainController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVcIntial)
        window.rootViewController = mainController
}else{
       let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: [loginStoryboard] , bundle: nil)
        let mainVcIntial = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: [Login VC])
        let mainController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVcIntial)
        window.rootViewController = mainController
}
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
```